# Problemas a la hora de encontrar el certificado por .net core

Tags: docker, .net-core, certificado-ssl, kubernetes

Tengo estas dos clases una que registra el certificado y otra que lo consume pero me da problemas con el certificado.

me da que la contraseña no es correcta del certificado, pero si es correcta.
ya eh intentado instalar el certificado por docker y es peor no encuentra el certificado.
el api de .net core la instalo por medio de docker y kubernetes. pero el servicio que consume es externo es wcf(SOAP) y ocupa ese certificado para ejecutarlo. ya lo probe localmente y funciona. pero a la hora de instalarlo en el kubernetes da el error de la contraseña.

```
public class BusinessInstaller : IInstallerServices
    {
        public void InstallServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment _environment)
        {
            #region Business

            var password = configuration.GetSection("RSA:Password").Value;

            // Aquí se agrega el certificado al almacén de certificados
            var cert = new X509Certificate2("CRICPAIBSAPP1.com.pfx", password);
            using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                store.Add(cert);
            }

            services.AddTransient<IAutenticationServices, AutenticationServices>();
            #endregion
        }
    }



public class AutenticationServices : IAutenticationServices
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpclient;
        private readonly ILogger<AutenticationServices> _logger;
        public AutenticationServices(IHttpClientFactory httpClient, ILogger<AutenticationServices> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            _httpclient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        }

        public async Task<object> GetResultTokenRSA(TokenRSA request)
        {
            ValidarTokenRequest req = new ValidarTokenRequest(new ValidarTokenRequestBody(request.Token, request.UsuarioRSA, true, true, string.Empty));
            ValidarTokenResponse? res = null;
            bool error = false;
            string strMsg = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var respuesta = new wsValidacionesRSASoapClient(wsValidacionesRSASoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.wsValidacionesRSASoap);

                respuesta.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                    StoreName.Root,
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                    "CRICPAIBSAPP1.com"
                );

                res = await respuesta.ValidarTokenAsync(request.Token, request.UsuarioRSA, true, true, string.Empty);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = true;
                strMsg = ex.Message;
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }

            bool tokenValido = (res != null) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(res.Body.pMensaje) && !res.Body.pSiguieneToken && !res.Body.pEstablecerPIN);
            return new  { TokenValido = tokenValido, UserToken = request.UsuarioRSA, Response = res , Error = error, MsgError = strMsg } ;
        }
}
```